# Importing a floor plan in netlogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo

beginner netlogo user here. I did some basic stuff like creating turtles and making them move in a loop and such. Then I found out in the NetLogo dictionary that by using the command `import-pcolors-rgb` so that the turtles can interact with them. So I took out a simple floor plan and see what happens. The import was successful. But the layout in NetLogo was incomplete. Like some of the walls are missing. I tried searching for tutorials but I couldn't find one. I also tried my turtle to move forward and forward until it reached a wall. I was expecting it to stop or give me an error but it just passed through. How can I make this happen?

Edit: I've researched some sample simulation models on how they made it like setep by step, or even in youtube. But couldn't find anything.
Tutorials and help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the image (can you include a link?), I would guess that what you're seeing as an incomplete import is due to the fact that `import-pcolors-rgb` applies colors from the imported image to the patches. However, a patch can only have one color- a patch will take on the color from the image that covers the greatest part of that patch. As far as why your turtles don't stop when they hit a wall- you need to program that behavior into the turtles. They need to be "told" to recognize different colors. Check out the"Look Ahead Example" model in the model library for a simple example.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for the late reply! I've been trying to make this work for so long. Like even making the whole floor layout one color, or cropping a portion of the layout. But I still couldn't make it complete. Some patches arent colored accorrdingly. Here is the floor plan that I'm playing with (https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/diamond/floor-plans) Also, I thought about making square turtles and code my moving turtles to avoid those square turtles. But dropped the idea since there is a gap between those square turtles when I'm trying to make a wall. I'll check out your suggestion!